# Is it possible to cancel hover event based on condition while still hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hover

I need to make my hover event, which executes a function, to stop running that function based on the condition of margin-top.

Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Joe_Foster/LwrVv/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function moveUp(){
$('#a').animate({
    "margin-top" : "-=" + 30},200, "linear", moveUp);
};
/*  $('.up').hover(function(){
    if ($m =='0px'){
    alert('stop');
    }
    else{
        moveUp();
    }
});
*/
$('.up').hover(function(){
    moveUp();
},
function(){
    $('#a').stop();
});


//---------------------------------------

function moveDown(){
$('#a').animate({
    "margin-top" : "+=" + 30},200, "linear", moveDown);
};
$('.down').hover(function(){
    moveDown();
},
function(){
    $('#a').stop();
});

});
```

Please help me before I burst more blood vessels in my eyes :)

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean with 'based on the condition of margin-top'?

Comment: My function causes my (colored black) div to move my container ('#a') up or down (by adjusting it's 'margin-top') depending on which black div you are hovering over. What I need is for the hover to stop executing the function when, for instance, 'margin-top' is '0px' or 'margin-top' is '450px' (for the sake of the argument).

Comment: The 'mouseleave' stops the function but I cant figure out how to stop the function based on a condition while still hovering (mouseenter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking at your JS Fiddle and while I'm not certain of what values you wished to stop at, here is the code I used to make it work:

JS:

```
    var upperThreshold = -607;
    var lowerThreshold = 0;
    function moveUp()
    {
        if ($("#a").css("marginTop").replace(/px/,'') <= upperThreshold)
        {
            console.log($("#a").css("marginTop"));
            $('#a').stop();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#a').animate({"margin-top" : "-=" + 30},200, "linear", moveUp);
        }
    }

    function moveDown()
    {
        if ($("#a").css("marginTop").replace(/px/,'') >= lowerThreshold)
        {
            console.log($("#a").css("marginTop"));
            $('#a').stop();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#a').animate({"margin-top" : "+=" + 30},200, "linear", moveDown);
        }        
    }

$(document).ready(function()
                  {

                      $('.down').hover(function()
                                       {
                                           moveDown();
                                       },
                                       function()
                                       {
                                           $('#a').stop();
                                       }
                                      );

                      $('.up').hover(function()
                                     {
                                        moveUp();
                                     },
                                     function()
                                     {
                                        $('#a').stop();
                                     }
                                    );
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/irishgeek82/ePdE5/

Please let me know if this works for you! :)

Comment: This is design has some issues, due to the use of magic values for knowing when to start and stop.

Comment: Thresholds clearly defined as variables are far from "magic" numbers.   Had I simply entered -607 and 0 inline I would consider your comment valid.  Further, the values selected were selected through experimentation leveraging the individuals jsFiddle.  I clearly state that I did not know where the individual wished to stop the animation, so I had it stop one frame from the end of the example list.  The person asking the question can adjust the threshold logic to their liking.  The answer, however, meets the criteria of the request.

Comment: IrishGeek82 - YES! Thank you! The logic works just as I need it to and I can now focus on making it more visually appealing. Again - I can't thank you enough!